# How to determine the continuity of bivariate functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, problem-solving

Consider a problem of the form $f(x,y) = \frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)}$ for $x \neq y$ and $f(x,y) = a$ for $x=y$ such that $a$ is a fixed real number and $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. And we need to show that this function is continuous for all values of $(x,y)$ in the domain.

Showing that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at all points $x \neq y$ is simple in the case where both the numerator and denominator are continuous and the denominator is not equal to $0$.

However, I'm not sure what the best approach is to show that the function is continuous for all $(x,y)$.

If there was an isolated point that needed to be considered (such as $(0,0)$), then I could simply treat that on its own. However, in this case, there are infinitely many points where $x=y$, and so I'm not quite sure what the best way to deal with this type of problem is.

I would be grateful for any input here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer.

If $f$ is translation invariant, i.e. $f(t+x,t+y)=f(x,y)$, then it suffices to check the continuity of $f$ at the origin.

If $f$ is general, then I guess we don't have a 'best' way to deal with its continuity along the line. The main reason is as follows.

For a translation invariant function, its behaviors around different points on the line are the same. We can call this property *uniformly behaves* (not a standard term. I just made it up for simplicity of statement). While for a general $f$, corresponding to general $g$ and $h$, the behaviors of $f$ around different points on the line can be quite different, i.e. *differently behaves* (again, just a made-up word corresponding to the one above). Thus, one should not expect that there is a 'simple' or 'best' way to identify all the continuous points of $f$ on the line.

Comment: @FD_bfa Notice, the parametrization for the line $y=x$ is just $r(t)=(t,t)$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then your problem about to study continuity of the function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1-\cos(x-y)}{(x-y)^{2}},\quad x=y,\\ \frac{1}{2},\quad x=y\end{cases}$ is just to study the continuity of the function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1-\cos(x-y)}{(x-y)^{2}},\quad (x,y)\not=(t,t),\\ \frac{1}{2},\quad (x,y)=(t,t)\end{cases}$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, we can use just the of definition by limit, that is, you need to see if $\lim_{(x,y)\to (t,t)}\frac{1-\cos(x-y)}{(x-y)^{2}}\overbrace{=}^{?}f(t,t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user1027216 this reduces down to $\frac{0}{0}$. Would it then just be a case of using l’hopitsls rule, or does this break down in the muktivariate case?

Comment: @user1027216 Or is it sufficient to show that $f(x,t) \rightarrow 0.5$ and  $f(t,y) \rightarrow 0.5$. As we already know that $f(t,t)=0.5$ by definition.

Comment: @FD_bfa You gotta treat $(x,y)$ as a whole and there is no L'Hopital's Rule for multiple variable limits. However, the good news is you can calculate the limit with polar coordinate system, cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177067/lhospital-rule-for-two-variable). As for your last comment, it is totally wrong. Because we are dealing with limits in $\mathbb R^2$, we gotta consider all possible directions. If you fix $x(=t)$ or $y(=t)$, only two paths are considered.

Comment: @FD_bfa Note that we can use polar coordinate system here because the limit point in $\mathbb R^2$ is of the form $(t,t)$. For limit points in $\mathbb R^2$ of more general forms, we may not find a suitable coordinate system to calculate the limits (of $f$).

Comment: @SamWong Thanks for the clarification. Would it also be sufficient to let t = x-y, and then use L'Hopital's rule? Since this now reduces to a single variable calculus problem?

Comment: @FD_bfa It is tempting to do the change of variable, but I feel like it is not valid. Our original limit is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(t,t)}$ where $t$ is fixed in $\mathbb R$. Now let $\alpha:=x-y$, and suppose $\alpha \to 0$. We can conclude that $|x-y| \to 0$, which implies $(x,y) \to (\tilde{t},\tilde{t})$ for some $\tilde{t}\in \mathbb R$. The problem is, $t$ may not be equal to $\tilde{t}$. And so $\alpha \to 0$ is not equivalent to $\lim_{(x,y)\to(t,t)}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two ways (logically equivalent):

- Showing that $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)=f(x_{0})$.
- Showing that for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\varepsilon$ whether $|x-x_{0}|<\delta$.

We say that $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at every point of its domain.

Comment: The OP is not asking for the definition of continuity in general topological spaces. It is asking if there is a *best* way to identify all continuous points along a line.