# Heuristics for Lipschitz equivalence

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I'm studying for my finals in general topology and when I look at the definition of the Lipschitz equivalence of two metrics as:

> Let $d(x,y)$  and $d'(x,y)$ be metrics on a non-empty set $X$. We define $d$ and $d'$ to be Lipschitz equivalent if there exists $\alpha, \beta > 0$ such that

$$\alpha d'(x,y) \leq d(x,y) \leq\beta d'(x,y) .$$

I noticed that there is a similarity between this definition and the $\Theta-$ notation for the asymptotics of a function. I'm wondering if I could possibly use the definition of Lipschitz eqivalence as

$$\lim_{x,y\to \infty} \frac{d(x,y)}{d'(x,y)}=v$$

where $0<v<\infty$ as an equivalence formulation of Lipschitz equivalence? Also, is there a version of L'Hopital's rule for multivariate functions?

Comment: For your last question, see [L'Hôpital in several variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77723/lhopital-in-several-variables).

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed some similarity. But, in the $\Theta$-notion we have the idea that this approximation only holds for sufficiently large $x$, while here we have that the inequality holds for *all* pairs of points, so it's uniform. Also, it's unclear what the equivalent formulation would be  of the notion of limit towards infinity, e.g. What if a metric space is bounded?

Answer (score 1):

You are on to something here, although the guess is incorrect. Suppose the Lipschitz equivalence *fails*: that is, either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ fails to exist. For definiteness, consider the case then $\alpha$ fails to exist; the other case amounts to exchanging $d$ and $d'$. Since there is no $\alpha$, there exist sequences $x_n$, $y_n$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{d'(x_n,y_n)} = 0  \tag{1}$$
How can (1) happen? Maybe $d'$ is large, or maybe $d$ is small. So, passing to a suitable subsequence, we obtain either
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{d'(x_n,y_n)} = 0, \quad \lim_{n}  d'(x_n,y_n) = \infty$$
or 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{d'(x_n,y_n)} = 0, \quad \lim_{n}  d(x_n,y_n) = 0 $$
What this says is that if the Lipschitz equivalence fails, it fails on an extreme scale for one of the metrics: either   very large, or   very small scale.

The above observations are actually useful, especially in two special cases:

1. the space is bounded (both $d,d'$ are bounded from above)
2. the space is discrete (nonzero distances $d,d'$ are bounded from below)

In the first case we are only concerned with small scale behavior; in the second case only with large scale behavior.

---

> Also, is there a version of L'Hopital's rule for multivariate functions?

Certainly not on general metric spaces, where we don't have derivatives. On $\mathbb R^n$? Can't say for sure. You could   ask this as a separate question.